# Jest testing component getting "TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.withRouter) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-v4, babel-jest

This is a whopper.

For some reason, jest and babel won't import and transpile react-router 4's withRouter.

I recently updated from react-router 3 to react-router 4.  My single page app compiles via webpack just fine, and I can navigate my local dev version just fine in the browser.

However, tests that involve components that are wrapped with the withRouter HOC fail.

Specifically, if the component being tested has a descendant component that uses the withRouter HOC, you can't even import withRouter.  A console log shows that withRouter is imported as "undefined"

The  folder has the following files.

```
app/
├── src/
    ├── LoginContainer.jsx
    ├── LoginForm/
        ├── index.js
        └── LoginForm.jsx
```

LoginContainer (A react container component)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

export default class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentForm: props.form };
    this.changeForm = this.changeForm.bind(this);
  }

  changeForm(form) {
    // handle when someone changes something.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <LoginForm {...this.props} changeForm={this.changeForm} data-form={this.state.currentForm} />
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

LoginForm/index.js (basically a HOC that wraps LoginForm.jsx)

```
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

// NO MATTER WHAT I DO...
// withRouter is undefined.
// If I do import * as bob from 'react-router'
// bob then equals { default: {} }
// bob is blank!

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

For some reason, I can't import withRouter when testing. All other modules import just fine, only withRouter is causing issues.

- react-router 4.2.0 and react-router-dom 4.2.2 are both installed as dependencies
- Other components that use things like Link or Route pass tests just fine

**UPDATE**

I think it has to do with jest + babel.  If I switch the import statement to a require statement, it works!

```
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

// THIS WORKS! But I don't want to deviate from ES6 just for a test.
const withRouter = require('react-router/index.js').withRouter;

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

Comment: Just a sanity check, did you verify that the content of `node_modules` is correct in the test environment, i.e. that the correct version of `react-router` is installed? You might want to remove the whole `node_modules` and reinstall to just to make sure. Btw, do you know that `react-router` and `react-router-dom` are [different npm packages](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router#packages)? You have to install both to get the common functions and DOM-specific navigation elements.

Comment: I ran `rm -rf ./node_modules ./.babel-cache; npm install` and it still has the same issue.  This only is happening when importing withRouter.  No other modules have an issue.

Comment: Can you share your version of react-router

Comment: "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Comment: @mrbinky3000 Did you manage to solve the problem? I have the same one

Comment: @martin36 we updated to react-router 5 and it worked.